# Invalid operands error while overloading the += operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

sentence class

```
class sentence
{   
    public:
        sentence(); 
        ~sentence();
        void testing(sentence *& s);
        sentence operator+=(char * sentence_to_add);
    protected:
        node * head;
};
```

Implementation (its not correct, just testing if it works)

```
sentence sentence::operator+=(char * sentence_to_add) 
{
    cout << "testing" << endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Testing said operator

```
void sentence::testing(sentence *& s)
{
    char * test_string = new char[5000];
    cout << "please enter a string: " << endl;
    cin.getline(test_string, 5000, '\n');
    s += test_string;
}
```

G++ compiler error

```
sentence.cpp: In member function âvoid sentence::testing(sentence*&)â:
sentence.cpp:124:7: error: invalid operands of types âsentence*â and âchar*â to binary âoperator+â
sentence.cpp:124:7: error:   in evaluation of âoperator+=(class sentence*, char*)â
```

What am I doing wrong? Because technically this should work. Since the lvalue is the pointer to class object, and the rvalue is the char array. So I'm pretty sure the operands are not invalid...

edit/update:
prototype

```
sentence & operator+=(const char * sentence_to_add);
```

implementation

```
sentence & sentence::operator+=(const char * sentence_to_add) 
{
    cout << "testing" << endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function takes a pointer, not an object.  Just take a reference (`sentence&`.)

As an aside, your operator(s) should return a reference, not a copy.

Comment: `Just take a reference (sentence&.)` - it should be a `const sentence&` (and `const char*` for the other overload).

Comment: I'm still getting the invalid operands with that, but when I do `*(s) += test_string;` it compiles and works just fine. Could you please explain that?

Comment: @TonyD: That function modifies its argument, so no, it should not take a const reference. You're right about the input to the operator though.

Comment: It's *this that's modified in operator+=, not the argument.

Comment: @TonyD: I'm confused... the only function that takes a `sentence&` is `sentence::testing`. You said " it should be a const sentence&", but no, it can't be.  You couldn't have been talking about `operator+`. What are you saying exactly?

Comment: @EdS.: sorry Ed - as per the "for the other overload" in my first comment, I had somehow thought there were `operator+=` overloads for both `char*` and `sentence&` (and both of which ought to have been `const`), but looking at the question again I see things never got that far.  Apologies for the harassment ;-o, and +1 from me.

Comment: @TonyD: Yeah, I figured as much.  Easy mistake to make, no problem.